# Android 4.0 Switch for Custom Theme

Tags: android, themes, switch-statement

I am trying to use a Switch (toggle) in android 4.0 API.

If I use my customized theme for the activity there is an error showing
null pointer exception.

`switchStyle` not found.

How can I use default android switch in custom theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your custom theme must have a parent theme of one of the default themes: Holo / HoloLight / HoloLightDarkActionBar

That way, anything that you don't manually define will be picked from the default.

Comment: But there is a problem I am using Custom title bar so I have the use Black as parent theme . But Theme.Black does not contain style for switch.
What can be done to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Switch style is not public, it is not possible to extend the style, you need to set a background image. Have a look at https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary or https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary